# Alfresco 5 update node properties via rest service

Tags: rest, alfresco

I am wondering is it possible to update node properties in Alfresco 5 using REST service? 
I know that in earlier versions it was possible with the following call:

PUT /alfresco/service/api/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id},

and adding properties to update in the request body, but i cannot seem to confirm this is possible with alfresco 5, and hitting the url with postman is returning 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not avilable in 5.x

Similar service is

```
Node metadata storage service
POST /alfresco/service/api/metadata/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}

    ---
    Node metadata storage service.
    ---
    Authentication: user
    Transaction:    required
    Format Style:   argument
    Default Format: json
    Id: org/alfresco/repository/metadata/metadata.post
    Descriptor: classpath:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/metadata/metadata.post.desc.xml
```